# Cookie-session changes ID after reload when cookie path in root directory

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have a website written in PHP which uses session through cookies. It works perfectly when the app is in a subdirectory, because the cookie path is set to `/sub/`.

When I try to set up my website in the root directory of my domain (http://domain.tld/index.php), I set the cookie path to "/". According to the PHP documentation, this should not be an issue :

> session_set_cookie_params 
>   Path on the domain where the cookie will
>   work. **Use a single slash ('/') for all paths on the domain**.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Unfortunatly, in this case the sessionID seems to change after each page reload. It happens in Chrome and Opera, but for whatever reason, it works with Firefox.

By the way, if the session is not persistent, I can't login or do anything...

Does anyone have already experienced something like this ? Or have an idea ?

EDIT : It happens with Apache on Fedora and CentOS.

Comment: What happens if you simply don't set it when there is no path present?

Comment: It works ! It was so simple... Thank you Charles.

Comment: Actually, I just realized that I was setting it at '//' instead of '/'. That's why it didn't work.